# Why $f(x) = 5x$ is not a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Why the function $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $f(x) = 5x$ is not a ring homorphism, since $f(a+b) = 5(a+b) = 5a + 5b = f(a) + f(b)$, and same for $f(a \cdot b)$.

Comment: You said *same for f(ab)*, you should have written it : $f(ab)=5(ab)\neq f(a)f(b)=5a5b=25(ab)$ to notice it is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring, to be a homomorphism must have $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

But $30=f(6)=f(2\cdot 3) \neq f(2)\cdot f(3)=10\cdot 15=150$.

Comment: Even without requiring $f(1)=1$ (not all authors require this of ring homomorphisms), we still need to have $f(1)=f(1)^2$, which we clearly don't have.

Comment: @Arthur indeed, but the alternative $f(1)=0$ would lead to trivial $f=0$, so it is quite an obvious requirement to force $f(1)=1$.

Comment: In this case, sure. But as a general requirement for ring homomorphisms, $f(1)=1$ is not always assumed.

Comment: It depends if you consider unit rings or just rings. In this case, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a unit ring, $f(1)$ must be equal to $1$. But even if we consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring ("forgetting" the unit), this map doesn't preserve multiplication, so it's not an homomorphism.

Comment: @user289143 Not quite right. There are rings with units and homomorphisms inbetween not being unit-preserving. Eg: take any ring $R$ with unit $1_R$ and send $R$ to $\text{M}_2(R)$ by embedding into the upper-left corner with zeroes elsewhere. This is an injective homomorphism not sending $1_R$ to the unit in $\text{M}_2(R)$.